# IBM - Navigator Custom Action

Tags: dojo, ibm-content-navigator

I need to develop a IBM ICN plugin that do the following steps.

- the user search for an item of class A;
- the user select one item and click on 'Action Menu' and choose my custom action called 'Show other document'
- after that the user views a document of class B.

I developed a SamplePluginAction starting from IBM Sample example, I edited services so in the response I have the documentId of class B but for now I can only open a simple Message Dialog where I can see the documentId.

I think that is not the right way. I see that there is OpenActionDocument but I can't find an example.

Can anyone help me to understand which steps I have to implement? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to construct a url for viewing document and open that in a new browser window.

See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/content-navigator/3.0.x?topic=client-constructing-url-content-navigator#eucco106 => "Viewing documents" as for how to construct an url for viewing a document.